# How to make text widget static

Tags: python, tkinter

After changing the font size of the widget text increases , how to make it static?

[image: screenshot]

I'm giving you all the code so you can run the program. So do not swear

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Toplevel, Listbox, StringVar, BooleanVar, TclError
from tkinter import filedialog, scrolledtext,Menu,END,messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import Checkbutton, Frame, Label, Button, Scrollbar, Style, Entry
from tkinter.font import families, Font
from locale import getdefaultlocale
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

__version__ = "2.0.2"

# --- translation
EN = {"Cancel": "Cancel", "Bold": "Bold", "Italic": "Italic",
      "Underline": "Underline", "Overstrike": "Strikethrough"}
FR = {"Cancel": "Annuler", "Bold": "Gras", "Italic": "Italique",
      "Underline": "Souligné", "Overstrike": "Barré"}
LANGUAGES = {"fr": FR, "en": EN}

if getdefaultlocale()[0][:2] == "fr":
    TR = LANGUAGES["fr"]
else:
    TR = LANGUAGES["en"]

class FontChooser(Toplevel):
    """.Font chooser dialog."""

    def __init__(self, master, font_dict={}, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser",
                 **kwargs):
        """
        Create a new FontChooser instance.
        Arguments:
            master: master window
            font_dict: dictionnary, like the one returned by the .actual
                       method of a Font object:
                        {'family': 'DejaVu Sans',
                         'overstrike': False,
                         'size': 12,
                         'slant': 'italic' or 'roman',
                         'underline': False,
                         'weight': 'bold' or 'normal'}
            text: text to be displayed in the preview label
            title: window title
            **kwargs: additional keyword arguments to be passed to
                      Toplevel.__init__
        """
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.title(title)
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
        self._validate_family = self.register(self.validate_font_family)
        self._validate_size = self.register(self.validate_font_size)

        # --- variable storing the chosen font
        self.res = ""

        style = Style(self)
        style.configure("prev.TLabel", background="white")
        bg = style.lookup("TLabel", "background")
        self.configure(bg=bg)

        # --- family list
        self.fonts = list(set(families()))
        self.fonts.append("TkDefaultFont")
        self.fonts.sort()
        for i in range(len(self.fonts)):
            self.fonts[i] = self.fonts[i].replace(" ", "\ ")
        max_length = int(2.5 * max([len(font) for font in self.fonts])) // 3
        self.sizes = ["%i" % i for i in (list(range(6, 17)) + list(range(18, 32, 2)))]
        # --- font default
        font_dict["weight"] = font_dict.get("weight", "normal")
        font_dict["slant"] = font_dict.get("slant", "roman")
        font_dict["underline"] = font_dict.get("underline", False)
        font_dict["overstrike"] = font_dict.get("overstrike", False)
        font_dict["family"] = font_dict.get("family",
                                            self.fonts[0].replace('\ ', ' '))
        font_dict["size"] = font_dict.get("size", 10)

        # --- creation of the widgets
        # ------ style parameters (bold, italic ...)
        options_frame = Frame(self, relief='groove', borderwidth=2)
        self.font_family = StringVar(self, " ".join(self.fonts))
        self.font_size = StringVar(self, " ".join(self.sizes))
        self.var_bold = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["weight"] == "bold")
        b_bold = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Bold"],
                             command=self.toggle_bold,
                             variable=self.var_bold)
        b_bold.grid(row=0, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=(4, 2))
        self.var_italic = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["slant"] == "italic")
        b_italic = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Italic"],
                               command=self.toggle_italic,
                               variable=self.var_italic)
        b_italic.grid(row=1, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=2)
        self.var_underline = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["underline"])
        b_underline = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Underline"],
                                  command=self.toggle_underline,
                                  variable=self.var_underline)
        b_underline.grid(row=2, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=2)
        self.var_overstrike = BooleanVar(self, font_dict["overstrike"])
        b_overstrike = Checkbutton(options_frame, text=TR["Overstrike"],
                                   variable=self.var_overstrike,
                                   command=self.toggle_overstrike)
        b_overstrike.grid(row=3, sticky="w", padx=4, pady=(2, 4))
        # ------ Size and family
        self.var_size = StringVar(self)
        self.entry_family = Entry(self, width=max_length, validate="key",
                                  validatecommand=(self._validate_family, "%d", "%S",
                                                   "%i", "%s", "%V"))
        self.entry_size = Entry(self, width=4, validate="key",
                                textvariable=self.var_size,
                                validatecommand=(self._validate_size, "%d", "%P", "%V"))
        self.list_family = Listbox(self, selectmode="browse",
                                   listvariable=self.font_family, highlightthickness=0, exportselection=False, width=max_length)
        self.list_size = Listbox(self, selectmode="browse",
                                 listvariable=self.font_size, highlightthickness=0, exportselection=False, width=4)
        scroll_family = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.list_family.yview)
        scroll_size = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.list_size.yview)
        self.preview_font = Font(self, **font_dict)
        if len(text) > 30:
            text = text[:30]
        self.preview = Label(self, relief="groove", style="prev.TLabel", text=text, font=self.preview_font, anchor="center")

        self.list_family.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_family.set)
        self.list_size.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_size.set)
        self.entry_family.insert(0, font_dict["family"])
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        self.entry_size.insert(0, font_dict["size"])
        try:
            i = self.fonts.index(self.entry_family.get().replace(" ", "\ "))
        except ValueError:
            i = 0
        self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
        self.list_family.selection_set(i)
        self.list_family.see(i)
        try:
            i = self.sizes.index(self.entry_size.get())
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_size.selection_set(i)
            self.list_size.see(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        self.entry_family.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=(10, 1), padx=(10, 0))
        self.entry_size.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew", pady=(10, 1), padx=(10, 0))
        self.list_family.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", pady=(1, 10), padx=(10, 0))
        self.list_size.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew", pady=(1, 10), padx=(10, 0))
        scroll_family.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ns', pady=(1, 10))
        scroll_size.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='ns', pady=(1, 10))
        options_frame.grid(row=0, column=4, rowspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10)

        self.preview.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="eswn", padx=10, pady=(0, 10), ipadx=4, ipady=4)
        button_frame = Frame(self)
        button_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=(0, 10), padx=10)
        Button(button_frame, text="Ok", command=self.ok).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, sticky='ew')
        Button(button_frame, text=TR["Cancel"], command=self.quit).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, sticky='ew')
        self.list_family.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.update_entry_family)
        self.list_size.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.update_entry_size, add=True)
        self.list_family.bind("<KeyPress>", self.keypress)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Return>", self.change_font_family)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Tab>", self.tab)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Return>", self.change_font_size)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Down>", self.down_family)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Down>", self.down_size)
        self.entry_family.bind("<Up>", self.up_family)
        self.entry_size.bind("<Up>", self.up_size)
        self.bind_class("TEntry", "<Control-a>", self.select_all)

        self.wait_visibility(self)
        self.grab_set()
        self.entry_family.focus_set()
        self.lift()

    def select_all(self, event):
        event.widget.selection_range(0, "end")

    def keypress(self, event):
        key = event.char.lower()
        l = [i for i in self.fonts if i[0].lower() == key]
        if l:
            i = self.fonts.index(l[0])
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_family.selection_set(i)
            self.list_family.see(i)
            self.update_entry_family()

    def up_family(self, event):
        try:
            i = self.list_family.curselection()[0]
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i <= 0:
                i = len(self.fonts)
            self.list_family.see(i - 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i - 1)
        except TclError:
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            i = len(self.fonts)
            self.list_family.see(i - 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i - 1)
        self.list_family.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def up_size(self, event):
        """Navigate in the size listbox with up key."""
        try:
            s = self.var_size.get()
            if s in self.sizes:
                i = self.sizes.index(s)
            elif s:
                sizes = list(self.sizes)
                sizes.append(s)
                sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
                i = sizes.index(s)
            else:
                i = 0
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i <= 0:
                i = len(self.sizes)
            self.list_size.see(i - 1)
            self.list_size.select_set(i - 1)
        except TclError:
            i = len(self.sizes)
            self.list_size.see(i - 1)
            self.list_size.select_set(i - 1)
        self.list_size.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def down_family(self, event):
        """Navigate in the family listbox with down key."""
        try:
            i = self.list_family.curselection()[0]
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i >= len(self.fonts):
                i = -1
            self.list_family.see(i + 1)
            self.list_family.select_set(i + 1)
        except TclError:
            self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_family.see(0)
            self.list_family.select_set(0)
        self.list_family.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def down_size(self, event):
        """Navigate in the size listbox with down key."""
        try:
            s = self.var_size.get()
            if s in self.sizes:
                i = self.sizes.index(s)
            elif s:
                sizes = list(self.sizes)
                sizes.append(s)
                sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
                i = sizes.index(s) - 1
            else:
                s = len(self.sizes) - 1
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            if i < len(self.sizes) - 1:
                self.list_size.selection_set(i + 1)
                self.list_size.see(i + 1)
            else:
                self.list_size.see(0)
                self.list_size.select_set(0)
        except TclError:
            self.list_size.selection_set(0)
        self.list_size.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')

    def toggle_bold(self):
        """Update font preview weight."""
        b = self.var_bold.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(weight=["normal", "bold"][b])

    def toggle_italic(self):
        """Update font preview slant."""
        b = self.var_italic.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(slant=["roman", "italic"][b])

    def toggle_underline(self):
        """Update font preview underline."""
        b = self.var_underline.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(underline=b)

    def toggle_overstrike(self):
        """Update font preview overstrike."""
        b = self.var_overstrike.get()
        self.preview_font.configure(overstrike=b)

    def change_font_family(self, event=None):
        """Update font preview family."""
        family = self.entry_family.get()
        if family.replace(" ", "\ ") in self.fonts:
            self.preview_font.configure(family=family)

    def change_font_size(self, event=None):
        """Update font preview size."""
        size = int(self.var_size.get())
        self.preview_font.configure(size=size)

    def validate_font_size(self, d, ch, V):
        """Validation of the size entry content."""
        l = [i for i in self.sizes if i[:len(ch)] == ch]
        i = None
        if l:
            i = self.sizes.index(l[0])
        elif ch.isdigit():
            sizes = list(self.sizes)
            sizes.append(ch)
            sizes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
            i = min(sizes.index(ch), len(self.sizes))
        if i is not None:
            self.list_size.selection_clear(0, "end")
            self.list_size.selection_set(i)
            deb = self.list_size.nearest(0)
            fin = self.list_size.nearest(self.list_size.winfo_height())
            if V != "forced":
                if i < deb or i > fin:
                    self.list_size.see(i)
                return True
        if d == '1':
            return ch.isdigit()
        else:
            return True

    def tab(self, event):
        """Move at the end of selected text on tab press."""
        self.entry_family = event.widget
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        return "break"

    def validate_font_family(self, action, modif, pos, prev_txt, V):
        """Completion of the text in the entry with existing font names."""
        if self.entry_family.selection_present():
            sel = self.entry_family.selection_get()
            txt = prev_txt.replace(sel, '')
        else:
            txt = prev_txt
        if action == "0":
            txt = txt[:int(pos)] + txt[int(pos) + 1:]
            return True
        else:
            txt = txt[:int(pos)] + modif + txt[int(pos):]
            ch = txt.replace(" ", "\ ")
            l = [i for i in self.fonts if i[:len(ch)] == ch]
            if l:
                i = self.fonts.index(l[0])
                self.list_family.selection_clear(0, "end")
                self.list_family.selection_set(i)
                deb = self.list_family.nearest(0)
                fin = self.list_family.nearest(self.list_family.winfo_height())
                index = self.entry_family.index("insert")
                self.entry_family.delete(0, "end")
                self.entry_family.insert(0, l[0].replace("\ ", " "))
                self.entry_family.selection_range(index + 1, "end")
                self.entry_family.icursor(index + 1)
                if V != "forced":
                    if i < deb or i > fin:
                        self.list_family.see(i)
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def update_entry_family(self, event=None):
        """Update family entry when an item is selected in the family listbox."""
        #  family = self.list_family.get("@%i,%i" % (event.x , event.y))
        family = self.list_family.get(self.list_family.curselection()[0])
        self.entry_family.delete(0, "end")
        self.entry_family.insert(0, family)
        self.entry_family.selection_clear()
        self.entry_family.icursor("end")
        self.change_font_family()

    def update_entry_size(self, event):
        """Update size entry when an item is selected in the size listbox."""
        #  size = self.list_size.get("@%i,%i" % (event.x , event.y))
        size = self.list_size.get(self.list_size.curselection()[0])
        self.var_size.set(size)
        self.change_font_size()

    def ok(self):
        """Validate choice."""
        self.res = self.preview_font.actual()
        self.quit()

    def get_res(self):
        """Return chosen font."""
        return self.res

    def quit(self):
        self.destroy()
def askfont(master=None, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser", **font_args):
    chooser = FontChooser(master, font_args, text, title)
    chooser.wait_window(chooser)
    return chooser.get_res()

def edit_font():
    font = askfont(root, title="Choose a font")
    if font:
            font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
            font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
            if font['underline']:
                font_str += ' underline'
            if font['overstrike']:
                font_str += ' overstrike'
            text.configure(font=font_str)

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1423x800")
# added weights so the widget resizes correctly with window
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="0.png")
lab=tk.Label(root, image = image)
lab.grid(row=0, column=0)

text=tk.Text(root,width = 60,height=15, font=Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
text.grid(row=0, column=0)

king=tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view=tk.Menu(king, tearoff=0)
view2=tk.Menu(view, tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Font',command=edit_font)

view.add_cascade(label='Text', menu=view2)
king.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the code you will most likely need to fix my problem:

```
def askfont(master=None, text="Abcd", title="Font Chooser", **font_args):
    chooser = FontChooser(master, font_args, text, title)
    chooser.wait_window(chooser)
    return chooser.get_res()

def edit_font():
    font = askfont(root, title="Choose a font")
    if font:
            font['family'] = font['family'].replace(' ', '\ ')
            font_str = "%(family)s %(size)i %(weight)s %(slant)s" % font
            if font['underline']:
                font_str += ' underline'
            if font['overstrike']:
                font_str += ' overstrike'
            text.configure(font=font_str)

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1423x800")
# added weights so the widget resizes correctly with window
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="0.png")
lab=tk.Label(root, image = image)
lab.grid(row=0, column=0)

text=tk.Text(root,width = 60,height=15, font=Font(family="Helvetica", size=10))
text.grid(row=0, column=0)

king=tk.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=king)

view=tk.Menu(king, tearoff=0)
view2=tk.Menu(view, tearoff=0)
view2.add_command(label='Font',command=edit_font)

view.add_cascade(label='Text', menu=view2)
king.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)

root.mainloop()
```

This will probably include setting the frame size and frame, as well as banning distribution, one of my friends said. Hope this helps you

Comment: _"I'm giving you all the code so you can run the program. So do not swear"_ - posting all of the code isn't appropriate. Please take the time to create a [mcve]. It shouldn't be hard -- you just need a text widget,  a button that changes the font size, and enough code to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the Text widget a fixed height and width and wrap it in a Frame with the same width and height and use `grid_propagate(False)`, when the text is made bigger the Text widget stays the same size.

```
import tkinter as tk
def fontUp():
    text.config(font = ("30"))
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")

frm = tk.Frame(root, height = 500, width = 500)
frm.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
frm.grid_propagate(False)

text = tk.Text(frm, height = 500, width = 500)
text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Font bigger", command = fontUp)
btn.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
```